# Relations between Kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $T^2=0$ if and only if 
$\operatorname{Im}(T) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(T)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Seeing more effort on your part would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: I am stuck on T^2=0.

Comment: You know what $T^2 = 0$ means? It means that $T(T(v)) = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: $T^2(v) = T(T(v))$, the exponent tells you how many times you apply $T$.

Comment: Ok, now it is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to know what the kernel and the image of a linear map really is.

Assume $T^2 = 0$, i.e. $T(T(v)) = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Then we have 
$$ T( \underbrace{ T(V) }_{=\operatorname{Im}(V)} ) = \{0\} \; ,$$
which means that $\operatorname{Im}(V) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(V)$.

On the other hand, if $\operatorname{Im}(T) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(T)$, then $T(w) = 0$ for each $w \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$. Since for each $v \in V$ we have $T(v) \in \operatorname{Im}(T)$, we see that $T^2 = 0$.